# AssertionError returns user balance

Tags: solidity, javascript

Smart contract issue I get on windows terminal:

```
checking balances
      1) returns user balance

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    Token.Transfer(
      from: <indexed> 0xB66Bfb831D668ECfa782Fe44a3fc7fa49b539F86 (type: address),
      to: <indexed> 0x44969cc7D21211c484426BB0f86407D12168eaff (type: address),
      value: 100000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
    )

    Exchange.Deposit(
      token: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
      user: 0x44969cc7D21211c484426BB0f86407D12168eaff (type: address),
      amount: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256),
      balance: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
    )


    ---------------------------
making orders
      ✓ tracks the newly created order (397ms)


  17 passing (40s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Exchange
       checking balances
         returns user balance:

      AssertionError: expected '0' to equal '1000000000000000000'
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +1000000000000000000
```

Here is the relevant code in JS:

```
import { tokens, ether, EVM_REVERT, ETHER_ADDRESS } from './helpers'

const Token = artifacts.require('./Token')
const Exchange = artifacts.require('./Exchange')

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()

contract('Exchange', ([deployer, feeAccount, user1]) => {
  let token
  let exchange
  const feePercent = 10

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Deploy token
    token = await Token.new()

    // Transfer some tokens to user1
    token.transfer(user1, tokens(100), { from: deployer })

    // Deploy exchange
    exchange = await Exchange.new(feeAccount, feePercent)
  })

  describe('deployment', () => {
    it('tracks the fee account', async () => {
      const result = await exchange.feeAccount()
      result.should.equal(feeAccount)
    })

    it('tracks the fee percent', async () => {
      const result = await exchange.feePercent()
      result.toString().should.equal(feePercent.toString())
    })
  })

  describe('fallback', () => {
    it('reverts when Ether is sent', async () => {
      await exchange.sendTransaction({ value: 1, from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
    })
  })

  describe('depositing Ether', () => {
    let result
    let amount

    beforeEach(async () => {
      amount = ether(1)
      result = await exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: amount})
    })

    it('tracks the Ether deposit', async () => {
      const balance = await exchange.tokens(ETHER_ADDRESS, user1)
      balance.toString().should.equal(amount.toString())
    })

    it('emits a Deposit event', async () => {
      const log = result.logs[0]
      log.event.should.eq('Deposit')
      const event = log.args
      event.token.should.equal(ETHER_ADDRESS, 'token address is correct')
      event.user.should.equal(user1, 'user address is correct')
      event.amount.toString().should.equal(amount.toString(), 'amount is correct')
      event.balance.toString().should.equal(amount.toString(), 'balance is correct')
    })
  })


  describe('withdrawing Ether', () => {
    let result
    let amount

    beforeEach(async () => {
      // Deposit Ether first
      amount = ether(1)
      await exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: amount })
    })

    describe('success', async () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        // Withdraw Ether
        result = await exchange.withdrawEther(amount, { from: user1 })
      })

      it('withdraws Ether funds', async () => {
        const balance = await exchange.tokens(ETHER_ADDRESS, user1)
        balance.toString().should.equal('0')
      })

      it('emits a "Withdraw" event', async () => {
        const log = result.logs[0]
        log.event.should.eq('Withdraw')
        const event = log.args
        event.token.should.equal(ETHER_ADDRESS)
        event.user.should.equal(user1)
        event.amount.toString().should.equal(amount.toString())
        event.balance.toString().should.equal('0')
      })

    })

    describe('failure', async () => {
      it('rejects withdraws for insufficient balances', async () => {
        await exchange.withdrawEther(ether(100), { from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
      })
    })
  })

  describe('depositing tokens', () => {
    let result
    let amount

    describe('success', () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        amount = tokens(10)
        await token.approve(exchange.address, amount, { from: user1 })
        result = await exchange.depositToken(token.address, amount, { from: user1 })
      })

      it('tracks the token deposit', async () => {
        // Check exchange token balance
        let balance
        balance = await token.balanceOf(exchange.address)
        balance.toString().should.equal(amount.toString())
        // Check tokens on exchange
        balance = await exchange.tokens(token.address, user1)
        balance.toString().should.equal(amount.toString())
      })

      it('emits a Deposit event', async () => {
        const log = result.logs[0]
        log.event.should.eq('Deposit')
        const event = log.args
        event.token.should.equal(token.address, 'token address is correct')
        event.user.should.equal(user1, 'user address is correct')
        event.amount.toString().should.equal(amount.toString(), 'amount is correct')
        event.balance.toString().should.equal(amount.toString(), 'balance is correct')
      })
    })

    describe('failure', () => {
      it('rejects Ether deposits', async() => {
        await exchange.depositToken(ETHER_ADDRESS, tokens(10), { from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
      })

      it('fails when no tokens are approved', async () => {
        // Don't approve any tokens before depositing
        await exchange.depositToken(token.address, tokens(10), { from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
      })
    })
  })

  describe('withdrawing tokens', () => {
    let result
    let amount

    describe('success', async () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        // Deposit tokens first
        amount = tokens(10)
        await token.approve(exchange.address, amount, { from: user1 })
        await exchange.depositToken(token.address, amount, { from: user1 })

        // Withdraw tokens
        result = await exchange.withdrawToken(token.address, amount, { from: user1 })
      })

      it('withdraws token funds', async () => {
        const balance = await exchange.tokens(token.address, user1)
        balance.toString().should.equal('0')
      })

      it('emits a "Withdraw" event', async () => {
        const log = result.logs[0]
        log.event.should.eq('Withdraw')
        const event = log.args
        event.token.should.equal(token.address)
        event.user.should.equal(user1)
        event.amount.toString().should.equal(amount.toString())
        event.balance.toString().should.equal('0')
      })
    })

    describe('failure', async () => {
      it('rejects Ether withdraws', async () => {
        await exchange.withdrawToken(ETHER_ADDRESS, tokens(10), { from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
      })

      it('fails for insufficient balances', async () => {
        // Attempt to withdraw tokens without depositing any first
        await exchange.withdrawToken(token.address, tokens(10), { from: user1 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVM_REVERT)
      })
    })
  })
          // ERROR BELOW!!
  describe('checking balances', () => {                 
    beforeEach(async () => {
      exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: ether(1) })
    })

    it('returns user balance', async () => {
      const result = await exchange.balanceOf(ETHER_ADDRESS, user1)
      result.toString().should.equal(ether(1).toString())
    })
  })

  describe('making orders', () => {
    let result

    beforeEach(async ()=> {
      result = await exchange.makeOrder(token.address, tokens(1), ETHER_ADDRESS, ether(1), { from: user1 })
    })

    it('tracks the newly created order', async () => {
      const orderCount = await exchange.orderCount()
      orderCount.toString().should.equal('1')
    })
  })
})
```

And relevant code in Solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./Token.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

// TODO:
// [X] Set the fee account
// [X] Deposit Ether
// [X] Withdraw Ether
// [X] Deposit tokens
// [X] Withdraw tokens
// [?] Check balances
// [ ] Make order
// [ ] Cancel order
// [ ] Fill order
// [ ] Charge fees

contract Exchange {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    // Variables
    address public feeAccount; // the account that receives exchange fees
    uint256 public feePercent; // the fee percentage
    address constant ETHER = address(0); // store Ether in tokens mapping with blank address
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public tokens;
    mapping(uint256 => _Order) public orders;
    uint256 public orderCount;

    // Events
    event Deposit(address token, address user, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
    event Withdraw(address token, address user, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
   
    event Order(
        uint256 id,
        address user,
        address tokenGet,
        uint256 amountGet,
        address tokenGive,
        uint256 amountGive,
        uint256 timestamp
    );

// a way to model the order
    struct _Order {
        uint256 id;
        address user;
        address tokenGet;
        uint256 amountGet;
        address tokenGive;
        uint256 amountGive;
        uint256 timestamp;
    }

    // add the order to storage

    constructor (address _feeAccount, uint256 _feePercent) public {
        feeAccount = _feeAccount;
        feePercent = _feePercent;
    }

    // Fallback: reverts if Ether is sent to this smart contract by mistake
    function() external {
        revert();
    }

    function depositEther() payable public {
        tokens[ETHER][msg.sender] = tokens[ETHER][msg.sender].add(msg.value);
        emit Deposit(ETHER, msg.sender, msg.value, tokens[ETHER][msg.sender]);
    }

    function withdrawEther(uint _amount) public {
        require(tokens[ETHER][msg.sender] >= _amount);
        tokens[ETHER][msg.sender] = tokens[ETHER][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
        emit Withdraw(ETHER, msg.sender, _amount, tokens[ETHER][msg.sender]);
    }

    function depositToken(address _token, uint _amount) public {
        require(_token != ETHER);
        require(Token(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount));
        tokens[_token][msg.sender] = tokens[_token][msg.sender].add(_amount);
        emit Deposit(_token, msg.sender, _amount, tokens[_token][msg.sender]);
    }

    function withdrawToken(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(_token != ETHER);
        require(tokens[_token][msg.sender] >= _amount);
        tokens[_token][msg.sender] = tokens[_token][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        require(Token(_token).transfer(msg.sender, _amount));
        emit Withdraw(_token, msg.sender, _amount, tokens[_token][msg.sender]);
    }
   // ERROR BELOW!
    function balanceOf(address _token, address _user) public view returns (uint256) {
        return tokens[_token][_user]; 
    }

  // a way to store the order
    function makeOrder(address _tokenGet, uint256 _amountGet, address _tokenGive, uint256 _amountGive) public {
        orderCount = orderCount.add(1);
        orders[orderCount] = _Order(orderCount, msg.sender, _tokenGet, _amountGet, _tokenGive, _amountGive, now); 
        //Epoch time (sec) epochconverter.com
        emit Order(orderCount, msg.sender, _tokenGet, _amountGet, _tokenGive, _amountGive, now);
    }
}
```

Using Ganache and here is helpers.js code:

```
export const ETHER_ADDRESS = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

export const EVM_REVERT = 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'

export const ether = (n) => {
    return new web3.utils.BN(
    web3.utils.toWei(n.toString(), 'ether')
    )
}

// Same as ether
export const tokens = (n) => ether(n)
```

The code seems to be functional but there some kind of logic issue with the amount in the
balances themselves.

Comment: Please only include the relevant portions of code. Personally I can say that I just give up trying to figure out the problem when there is so much irrelevant code around

Comment: sorry was a noob

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had this answered yet, but change

```
  // ERROR BELOW!!
  describe('checking balances', () => {                 
    beforeEach(async () => {
      exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: ether(1) })
    })
```

to this:

```
  // ERROR BELOW!!
  describe('checking balances', () => {                 
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await exchange.depositEther({ from: user1, value: ether(1) })
    })
```

that should solve your problem.